# Set div block to 100% of body

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the middle block (with grey background) to stretch to the sides of the browser.  I have been able to get this to happen with the following code:

```
#aboutBlock {
   background: #f2f2f1; 
   position:absolute; 
   left:0; 
   width: 100%;
}
```

The problem is now the div that follows shows up underneath this one, when it needs to appear directly after this div.

Comment: I would structure the html differently to achieve this

Comment: I agree with @Huangism, but if you want quick and dirty approach... `width: 100vw`, however please consider structural changes to your html.

Comment: If you are up for restructuring, I suggest a [structure like this](http://jsfiddle.net/9y0m34h2/).

Comment: I restructed things and was able to get that block to behave how I wanted.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have that element inside an element with a width of 950px:

```
.block1 {
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 48px 0;
}
```

You need to set `.block1` width to 100%, as well as elements above it all the way to and including the `<body>`, and take `position:absolute` off the `#aboutBlock`. You will then need to set the width for elements that should be 950px wide.

But like  Huangism said, I would probably structure the html differently.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `position: absolute`, the element is taken out of the layout of the document (other things on the page ignore it being there and just go behind/on top of it). It looks like your problem is that your "block1" div is set to only be a certain width and your "aboutBlock" is inside of that "block1". To fix this, you will either have to make "block1" be the full width of the page and make all of your other sections be specific width (looks like 950px) and centered (with `margin: 0 auto`) or do the following:

```
.aboutBlock {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.block1 {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

And add a:

```
<div style="clear: both; height: 0">&nbsp;</div>
```

Below the "aboutBlock".